# `Element does not exist in cache` error on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, browserstack

I have a test written in JavaScript, using WebdriverIO and Mocha libraries. The idea of the test to check if the elements in the website are functioning as expected.

Here's an excerpt of the test case:

```
describe('My test', () => {

  beforeEach( async () => {
   await browser.url('my_site_url');

      it ('The button should be clickable', async () => {
         let button = await $('#button-name');
         await button.click(); //test fails here on iOS Safari
         ... // the rest of the code
      });

      it ... //other test cases

   });
```

The problem that this test fails on iOS Safari and throws this error:
`Element does not exist in cache`

It works well on Android Chrome, Mac OS Safari, Windows Firefox, and Windows Chrome.

I also use BrowserStack tool to run these tests on different devices. The tool provides visual logs of how the tests have been performed. From the logs, I can visually see that the button element did appear properly. Also, I've manually retested it many times by inspecting the button element and can confirm that the name of the button is correct.

What could be the issue here? From the answers on the Internet, I suspect that my element could be staled, but not sure how that's possible since I use `await` until I click it.

Comment: is `$` JQuery in this case?

Comment: It's webdriverIO command: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$.html